# Insert textbox values to Oracle DB

Tags: vb.net, oracle

I've never done INSERT statement to Oracle in VB.NET, so I need a little help. My code doesn't work, after executing nothing happens - no errors and no Insert. What is wrong or what am I missing here ? (Field1 and Field2 are just table fields, not a primary key).

```
Imports System.Data
Imports Oracle.DataAccess.Client ' ODP.NET Oracle managed provider
Imports Oracle.DataAccess.Types

Public Class Save_Records 

      Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

     Const conn As String = "Data Source=MyDB;User Id=Lucky;Password=MyPassword;"

        Using cn As New OracleConnection(conn)

            cn.Open()

            Using cmd As New OracleCommand()
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT into MyTable (Field1,Field2) values('" & TxtField1.Text & "','" & TxtField2.Text & "')"
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            End Using

        End Using

      End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Perhaps a missing `commit`?

Comment: add also **cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text**

Comment: commit ? where should I add this ? I added cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text before cmd.CommandText and now I receive error: "External component has thrown exception".

Comment: You should be using database parameters to avoid sql injection issues. Are you getting any errors? What is the result of the `ExecuteNonQuery` statement?

Comment: @AndrewMortimer, read my previous post, this error is result of ExecuteNonQuery statement.

Comment: you kept the connection open...shouldn't you close it as well?

Comment: Get the connection and command into Using statements. Build the sql into a variable and show what it is before inserting it. Confirm that the sql runs on your database when you run it via a regular sql client.

Comment: @AndrewMortimer, see my edited question, you meant something like this  ? This now produces an error: " Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object." - on ExecuteNonQuery...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method is a starting place for how to insert into Oracle

```
Private Function insertRow(connectionString As String) As Boolean

    Using cn As OracleConnection = New OracleConnection(connectionString)

        cn.Open()

        Using cmd As OracleCommand = New OracleCommand()

            Const sql As String = "Insert into test_table (val1, val2) values (:var1, :var2)"
            cmd.Connection = cn
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("var1", TxtField1.Text))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("var2", TxtField2.Text))
            cmd.CommandText = sql
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        End Using

    End Using

End Function
```

Comment: I tried this, what are those parameters "test1" & "test2", should I add TxtField1 & TxtField2 there ?? I tried running your code, but again error: "External component has thrown an exception."...Am I missing some references ? see my decalaration above public class, in my edited question...

Comment: I have similar Imports to you and a project reference to Oracle.DataAccess. Can you inspect all the information in the Exception and see if it contains some more details on the failure?

Comment: "An unhandled exception of type 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException' occurred in Oracle.DataAccess.dll"....And under detail : "{"ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number"}". This is all I can see under this error :""External component has thrown an exception." - for ExecuteNonQuery statement.

Comment: Does your sql run when you run it against the database via your normal sql client (Toad / Oracle SQL Developer / sql+ worksheet / whatever)? Are you using parameters?

Comment: I'm not following you right now, but while I'm executing this code in VB.NET I have opened Toad Oracle. Reading from Oracle goes fine doing same, just not Insert...When I run Insert in Toad, my SQL does Error :"ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("MySchema"."MyTable"."PrimaryKey")....Is primary key a problem ? How do I automatically add it, Its a number field ?

Comment: Only you'd know how and where the primary key is derived. You'll need to look at the existing data or consult with the person who designed the table. You can see the data types by describing the table: "Desc MyTable;"

Comment: Well, primary key is problem indeed. I tried adding another parameter for It, and Insert worked. Do you maybe know how to make primary key number in Toad to automatically increase or add when you perform Insert ? Access does this nicely, but I can't figure out here how to do same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120406/discussion-between-andrew-mortimer-and-luckyluke82).